# I want to be clicking on the button automatically

Tags: jquery

I want to be clicking on the button  automatically

But how?

I tried this but did not succeed

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <script>
 $(function(){
 $("a").click(function(){
alert("hillo");
});
 });

$("a").click();

  </script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="http://google.com">google</a>


</body>

</html>
```

This well was used only but also did not succeed

```
$("a").click();
```

Comment: you ddnt knclude a reference to jQuery

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually include jQuery before you call `$(function...`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You also need the call to `.click()` to be inside the ready function.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have it `$("a").click()` will be called before the document ready event.  If you place it within the same document ready handler, it should work.

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        alert("hillo");
    });
    $("a").click();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things wrong with your code.

- You did not include a reference to jQuery: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
- The "automatic" call to `.click` is outside of the document .ready function
- [**http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/nww4S/**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/nww4S/)

> Your code as it *SHOULD* be:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("a").click(function(e) { alert("hillo"); });

            $("a").click();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try firing the event inside the `DOM handler`..

The `click()` evnet is **being fired even** before it is being assigned, As you have written it `outside the DOM handler`

Assuming you have included the jQuery file

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){  // $("a").on('click', function()   
                              //  this is better
       alert("hillo");
     });

    $("a").click();   // Moved it inside
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/XwjYj/